# Label/Titulo Fixado no marker - Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Eu estou trabalhando com a `Google Maps Api`, e preciso deixar o nome aparendo estaticamente em cima/baixo do `Marker`, eu queria colocar essa label/titulo ao criar o marker, como o `title`, alguém sabe uma forma simples de fazer isso ?

Eu gostaria de algo parecido com isso :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu marker está sendo inciado dessa forma:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
   map: map,
   title: localizacao.message.nome,
   icon: '../Content/imagens/Icones/Markers/green-marker.png'
 });
```

Desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar a *label* desta forma:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myPosition,
  label: 'Nome do Marker',
  map: map
});
```

Ela ficará no meio do ícone que escolheu, já uso essa `API` do `Maps` a algum tempo e ainda não descobri como mudar essa forma que aparece, porém quando preciso deixar exatamente como quero eu crio a imagem em um programa de edição de imagens e coloco ela no `icon`, exatamente como você colocou o `green-marker.png`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu acabei deixar um infoWindow aberta por padrão, mas já me ajudou bastante sua resposta.